# convert image to YUV format (different types: BT.601 or BT.709) and save it in the raw format

Tags: encode, codec, yuv

Is there a tool that can convert a given image (jpg) into YUV format and save it as a raw data ?

I tried Python PIL, but failed to find how to do this.

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows. Just in the Terminal, you can run:

```
convert input.jpg -depth 8 -colorspace Rec601YCbCr yuv:result.bin
```

or, for `Rec709YCbCr`, you can use:

```
convert input.jpg -depth 8 -colorspace Rec709YCbCr yuv:result.bin
```

---

Here is a little example of the process and reversing it:

```
# Create a gradient image, magenta-green, save as JPEG
convert -size 1024x768 gradient:magenta-lime input.jpg

# Convert to YUV, saving as raw YUV in "image.bin"
convert input.jpg -depth 8 -colorspace Rec601YCbCr yuv:image.bin

# Convert back from raw YUV back to JPEG to check
convert -size 1024x768 -depth 8 YUV:image.bin -set colorspace Rec601YCbCr -colorspace RGB result.jpg
```

Comment: Pleasure! Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

convert from jpg to yuv with ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i filename.jpg -pixel_format yuv420p -s 656x500 filename.yuv
```

`-pixel_format` can be `yuv420p` or `yuv422p` or `yuv444p`

`-s` is the resolution of the jpg

---

to view it

```
ffplay -f rawvideo -pixel_format yuv420p -video_size 656x500 -i filename.yuv
```

if video size isn't exact you will see garbage's.